# QuerySyntaxException: XXXX is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, запрос, orm

Пытаюсь сделать  HQL-запрос к сущности Pushdata, но выдает ошибку 500 QuerySyntaxException: Pushdata is not mapped

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="pushmaster")
 public class Pushdata {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "pushmaster_id_seq",
sequenceName = "pushmaster_id_seq",
allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
generator = "pushmaster_id_seq")
@Column(name="id", unique = true)
public int id;

private String title;
private String content;

public Pushdata (){

}

public Pushdata (String title, String content){
    this.title=title;
    this.content=content;
}

@Column(name = "title")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Column(name = "content")
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}}
```

Сам запрос

```
(List<Pushdata>)
            factoryClass.getSessionFactory().
                    openSession().createQuery(" from Pushdata" ).list();
```

Файл конфигурации

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="ru.spb.Pushdata"/>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, путем изменения кода создания сессии.
Я изменил метод “applySettings(configuration.getProperties())” на “configure()”

```
 Правильный код 
public class FactoryClass {

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public FactoryClass() {
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

Решение помог найти этот ресурс [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-test)